# Assign var only if every product in cart is part of the same category

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to assign a var to be used in an if statement it looks like this:

```
              {assign var="worldwide" value=false}
{assign var="idCategory" value=15}
{foreach from=$cart.products item=product}
    {if $product.id_category_default == $idCategory}
        {assign var="worldwide" value=true}
    {/if}
{/foreach}

{if $worldwide == true}

{/if}
```

In its current state it however is true if just one product of category value 15 is in cart. I want it so that it is only true if all products in cart are part of same category. I'm using Prestashop 1.7

Comment: That's some kind of template, no?  I think you are mixing too much business logic in with the presentation.

Comment: It's supposed to be part of a template, yes. I don't get the latter parts of your comment.

Comment: Templates are meant to display information, not do business logic.  For example, Wouldn't it be easier to figure that out in PHP, and then use a simple boolean in the template..  In PHP you could use something like `array_count_values` and see if there is one item in the array, that will tell you if they are all the same.  I doubt the template can do that.  But I have no idea what the data you are working with looks like as it's not provided.

Comment: I agree with @ArtisticPhoenix but still you want to achive it then  try {assign var="worldwide" value=true}
{assign var="idCategory" value=15}
{foreach from=$cart.products item=product}
    {if $product.id_category_default != $idCategory}
        {assign var="worldwide" value=false}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
{if $cart.products.length > 0 &&  $worldwide == true}

{/if}

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thank you for leading me in that direction. I changed the logic of my if statement to contain two variables so that I can create if $variable1 == true and if $variable 2 == false statements, which gives me enough flexibility to create the few if statements I need. I've also reduced the tpl file to simply contain the aforementioned if statement rather than the logic aswell.

Comment: @K.Koe - Glad it worked out for you.  A big thing in programing that a lot of novice or even some experienced developers miss is "separation of concerns" what that means is try to write code that does only 1 thing, but does it extremely well.  It's simple in theory, but it can be easy to just keep adding procedural code.  Mixing logic and display is one of those things.  Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cycle in reverse and abort when one of the elements is not what you want, like this:

```
{assign var="worldwide" value=true}
{assign var="idCategory" value=15}

{foreach from=$cart.products item=product}
    {if $product.id_category_default != $idCategory}
        {assign var="worldwide" value=false}
        {break}
    {/if}
{/foreach}

{if $worldwide == true}

{/if}
```